# SQLiteException: near "function": synxtax error: , while compiling

Tags: android, sqlite

```
package sg.edu.rp.c345.a02.corporatecall;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class DbAdapter {
    // Database properties
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "corporatecall.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION = "function";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY = "company";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_PHONE = "phone";

    // Create script
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_FAV = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_CONTACT_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CONTACT_NAME
            + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTACT_PHONE
            + " text not null);";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private MyDbHelper myDbHelper;

    // constructor create the wrapper to open and close the db
    public DbAdapter(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        myDbHelper = new MyDbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    // Insert new entry to the database or update if the task exist in the
    // database

    public long insertContact(String _name, String _function, String _company,
            String _phone) {
        Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_CONTACT_ID,
                KEY_CONTACT_NAME, KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION, KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY,
                KEY_CONTACT_PHONE }, KEY_CONTACT_NAME + "=\"" + _name + "\""
                + KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION + "=\"" + _function + "\""
                + KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY + "=\"" + _company + "\""
                + KEY_CONTACT_PHONE + "=\"" + _phone + "\"", null, null, null,
                null);

        int count = c.getCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int idColumn = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACT_ID);
            long id = c.getLong(idColumn);
            c.close();
            return updateContact(id, _name, _function, _company, _phone);
        } else {
            c.close();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_NAME, _name);
            contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION, _function);
            contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY, _company);
            contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_PHONE, _phone);

            Long test = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

            return test;
        }
    }

    // remove entry from the database based on the task name
    public boolean removeContact(String _name) {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, KEY_CONTACT_NAME + "='" + _name
                + "'", null) > 0;
    }

    // retrieve all the entries in the database
    public Cursor getAllContacts() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_CONTACT_ID,
                KEY_CONTACT_NAME, KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION, KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY,
                KEY_CONTACT_PHONE }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    // retrieve all the entries in the database
    public Cursor getAllContactsSearchName(String name) {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_CONTACT_ID,
                KEY_CONTACT_NAME, KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION }, KEY_CONTACT_NAME
                + " LIKE '%" + name + "%'", null, null, null, null);
    }

    public int updateContact(long _id, String _name, String _function,
            String _company, String _phone) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_NAME, _name);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_FUNCTION, _function);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_COMPANY, _company);
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTACT_PHONE, _phone);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, KEY_CONTACT_ID
                + "=" + _id, null);
    }

    public boolean removeAllContacts() {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, null) > 0;
    }

    private static class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public MyDbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        // Only gets called if the database does not exist on the phone
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_FAV);

        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion,
                int _newVersion) {
            // Drop old one
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_CREATE_FAV);
            // Create new one
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to add something into database using insertContact, there bound to be a SQLiteException.

SQLiteException: near "function": synxtax error: , while compiling:

How do I solve this? Help is appreciated ASAP.

Comment: what exactly does logcat say?

Comment: SQLiteException: near "function": synxtax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, function, company, phone FROM contacts, WHERE name="Wong Chun Kiat"function="Student"company="Republic Polytechn...:
at sg.edu.rp.c345.a02.corporatecall.DbAdapter.insertContact(DbAdapter.java:56)

Answer (score 1):

Function is a special SQLite keyword. You must enclose it in ` characters (right apostrophe). See details here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html